# Accurate trig in python

Tags: python

Straight to the chase I want to create a function which calculates the length of a step.

This is what I have:

```
def humanstep(angle):
    global human
    human[1]+=math.sin(math.radians(angle))*0.06
    human[2]+=math.cos(math.radians(angle))*0.06
```

So if the angle is 90 then the x value (human[1]) should equal 0.06 and the y value equal to 0.

Instead  the conversion between radians and degrees is not quite perfect and these values are returned.

```
[5.99999999999999, 3.6739403974420643e-16]
```

Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Duplicate of a thousand "math is broken"/"I get wrong results" questions, the answer is still "it ain't broken, it's floating point math".

Comment: What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic: http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Pop quiz, True or false: 5.999... == 6?

Comment: "Close enough for government work".

Comment: Assuming that you're using meters for units, the answer is accurate to about the size of the nucleus of a single gold atom. Is this accurate enough for your application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is representation error due to how floating point arithmetic works. See the following page from the Python documentation: [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

FTA:

> Note that this is in the very nature of binary floating-point: this is not a bug in Python, and it is not a bug in your code either. You’ll see the same kind of thing in all languages that support your hardware’s floating-point arithmetic (although some languages may not display the difference by default, or in all output modes).

For further reading, see the following pages:

- [The Perils of Floating Point](http://www.lahey.com/float.htm)
- [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1):

Exactly how accurate do you want? The above is accurate to 15dp.

Answer (score 1):

If you want *accurate* results, you are doing it correctly.

If you want mathematically *exact* results like `[6, 0]`, use a symbolic math library such as [sympy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html)

Notice that these are very different goals.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on [floating-point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point_numbers), as these calculations are naturally imperfect and some numbers cannot be represented accurately using Python's floating point numbers. (Obviously, a fixed number of bits cannot represent the infinitely many real numbers.

The short answer is no.  You can round if you want.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, it's floating point error. You can use the [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module, which can give you arbitrary precision math

Comment: Unless you have infinite RAM and CPU speed, the Decimal module will still suffer from all the usual limitations of floating-point math.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the representation issues inherent in floating-point numbers, you can use a [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html), but you will need to implement your own trigonometric functions. This will get you arbitrary precision but it will be rather slow.

Comment: Trig functions are transcendental, no rational representation will solve this specific question.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has said, this is to do with binary representation issues - 0.06 is not a "round" figure in binary (just like 1/3 is not in decimal).  It has nothing to do with the trig functions.  If you drop them out and just do:

```
human[1]+=0.06
human[2]+=0.0
```

and look at the results you will see the same.

However, in Python 2.7 up the representation of floating point numbers has been improved.  It will now display the shortest decimal number that gives that binary number - in this case I think it would display the answer you expect (only running 2.5 here so I can't quickly test).  See [this article](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html) for more information.